# Create menu that slides out over a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, html-table

I am trying to create a menu for each row in a table that starts as a hidden div and slides out or appears over the top of the table row when mousing over.  I started with the following:

```
<style>
    table {
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid gray;
        border-spacing: 0 !important;
    }
    table tr, table td {
        border-spacing: 0 !important;
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }
    .tableItems {
        cursor: default;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 100;
        float:left;
        display:none;
        height: 24px;
        border:none;
        border:collapse;
    }
    .tableItems ul {
        height: 100%;
        background: gray;
        -webkit-margin-before: 0 !important;
        -webkit-margin-after: 0 !important;
        -webkit-padding-start: 0 !important;
    }
    .tableItems ul li {
        color: white;
        height:100%;
        display:inline;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0 0 0 6px;
    }
</style>

<div class='tableItems'>
  <ul>
    <a href='#'><li>item 1</li></a>
    <a href='#'><li>item 2</li></a>
    <a href='#'><li>item 3</li></a>
  </ul>
</div>

<table>
<tr>
<td class='tableMenu'>
  Menu
  <!--
  <div class='tableMenu'>
    <div class='tableIcon'>
      Menu
    </div>
  </div>
  -->
</td>
<td>
  Something
</td>
<td>
  Something else
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
  $(".tableMenu").mouseenter(
    function() {
      $(".tableItems").show().animate({},175);
    }
  );
  $(".tableItems").mouseout(
    function() {
      $(".tableItems").hide();
    }
  );
</script>
```

Here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vmtSg/

I am able to get a menu to appear over the existing table row without affecting it, however the mouseout effect is not working properly, and I have no animated sliding action which I am not sure how to do.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mouseleave` instead of using `mouseout`, since `mouseout` causes events to bubble up and trigger the event when hovered over `a` tag (or any other descendants) as well which is inside of `.tableItems`. `mouseleave` doesn't cause event propagation so it gets trigerred only when you move out of `tableItems` and not its containing `li`s (when using mouseout)

```
$(".tableItems").mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).hide(500);
});
```

Apart from that with `(".tableItems").show().animate({},175);` you probably meant `(".tableItems").show(175);`.

From [official doc](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)

> This event type can cause many headaches due to event bubbling. For instance, when the mouse pointer moves out of the Inner element in this example, a mouseout event will be sent to that, then trickle up to Outer. This can trigger the bound mouseout handler at inopportune times. See the discussion for .mouseleave() for a useful alternative.

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/EBABaQu/3/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want a animation, well if you want to do it in JQuery it be simple just add slow or fast as a parameter to your hide and show methods.

```
$(".tableItems").show("slow");
$(".tableItems").hide("slow");
```

The way I would do it is with CSS [hover](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) and [transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).

Answer (score 0):

***slides out or appears over the top of the table row when mousing over***

Considering the above line i have created a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vmtSg/3/

```
var a=0-$('.tableItems').height();
$(".tableMenu").mouseenter(
    function() {
        $(".tableItems").show().animate({'top':''+a+'px'});
    }
);
$(".tableItems").mouseleave(
    function() {
        $(this).hide().animate({'top':'0px'});
    }
);
```